# ARKit – Semi-transparent texture pixels cause clipping in multiply blend mode

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am using the basic ARKit example and if I use two face meshes, one with the wireframe (back) and one with white boxes (front), I get odd result when using material blend mode multiply. As you can see in the image the semi-transparent pixels make the back mesh lose alpha in those areas (red arrows). The fully white and fully transparent pixel blend as expected.

I tried this same test in The default SceneKit example too and there the back object shows black at the semi-transparent pixels. The code is pretty basic for materials...

```
let m: SCNMaterial = SCNMaterial()
m.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
m.blendMode = SCNBlendMode.multiply
m.metalness.contents = 0.0
m.roughness.contents = 0.7
m.diffuse.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "atest")
p.firstMaterial = m
```

I would expect in multiply blend mode that all white and white-ish pixels to disappear (like they would in photoshop). If anyone can confirm this behavior and expectation, that would be great. thank you.

- (ARKit project)
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TEPzBMTz83PdV_XrwjzKXRVnIQ4Xov72/view?usp=sharing
- (SceneKit project)
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lGButxh9SfHg-0akniqKDKlL5qMCrk1P/view?usp=sharing

ARKit

[image]

SceneKit

[image: SceneKit black pixels]